# Cannot assign char to char[0] element

Tags: c#

I am a beginner to C. I know C and I am little new to objects and classes.

I thought to do some exercises using C#. So I want to encode the each character of a string. So I have planned to convert string (login_name) into char[] array and then loop through the each element of char[] array and perfom little manipulation and give some encoded value to the each character. Finally assign these values to another char[] sery and convert back this char[] sery to string.

I have written the basic idea. Take a look at this

```
char[] array = login_name.ToCharArray(); // Converted string to char array
char[] sery = null; //created a new array.is it neccessary to specify the size?
// convert the characters to int and perfom some opeartion;
// here i have ex-ored with 123 
int a =((int)array[0]) ^ 123; 
// now convert the encoded value to char and assign it to each element of char[] sery    
sery[0] = (char) a; but this statement gives run time error
```

Gives a run time error: create a new instance of char.

What does it mean?

Comment: sery is a null reference. What did you think would happen?

Comment: `char[] sery = null;` so `sery` is null, isn't it?

Comment: sorry but I thought it would initialize the values to zero I did not know that its actually reference.. @AnthonyPegram So u mean its actually reference instead of initializin a value ?

Comment: Thank you for letting me know its a reference :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the size of the array, otherwise in current form your `sery` is `null`

```
char[] sery = new char[array.Length]; //if the elements number would be same as array
```

Or you can use `List<T>`

```
List<char> seryList = new List<char>();
```